# How to ORDER BY one query only in a UNION ALL without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, union-all

I'm creating a list from unrelated data using `UNION ALL` in order to be saved to Excel in SQL Server 2008. Only one of the `SELECT` statements will have an `ORDER BY` and that is where my issue arises with the following error message

```
'The multi-part identifier "p.Category" could not be bound.'
```

This is a simplified working code example that I prefer to the second one below but breaks when uncommenting the first `SELECT` query:

```
CREATE TABLE #People(Category varchar(50), [Name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #People VALUES(1, 'Steve');
INSERT INTO #People VALUES(99, 'Anna');
INSERT INTO #People VALUES(2, 'Sarah'); 

-- Unrelated data SELECT query
--SELECT 'Best Employee' AS Matrix
--     , 'Alan' AS [Name]
--UNION ALL

SELECT CASE
           WHEN p.Category = 1
           THEN 'Very Active'
           WHEN p.Category = 2
           THEN 'Active '
           ELSE 'Departed'
       END AS Matrix
     , p.name AS [Name]
FROM #People p
ORDER BY p.Category;

DROP TABLE #People;
```

After some research I found that I could rewrite the query in the following way, which would give me the desired result in this small example but not something that I would consider ideal in my real case. Is there a way to give me the correct result without resorting to sub queries like in the working example below?

```
CREATE TABLE #People(Category varchar(50), [Name]  varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #People VALUES(1, 'Steve');
INSERT INTO #People VALUES(99, 'Anna');
INSERT INTO #People VALUES(2, 'Sarah'); 

SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- Unrelated data SELECT query
    SELECT 'Best Employee' AS Matrix
         , 'Alan' AS [Name]
         , '' AS Category

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CASE
               WHEN p.Category = 1
               THEN 'Very Active'
               WHEN p.Category = 2
               THEN 'Active '
               ELSE 'Departed'
           END Matrix
         , p.name AS [Name]
         , p.Category Category
    FROM #People p
) x
ORDER BY x.Category;

DROP TABLE #People;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` doesn't apply to just one `SELECT`, it applies to the whole result set, to the whole result after all rows are `UNION`ed. So, you need to include columns that will be used for sorting in each `SELECT` of the `UNION ALL`.

For example, the following is wrong syntax, because `ORDER BY` has to be after the last `SELECT` of the `UNION`.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN p.Category = 1
           THEN 'Very Active'
           WHEN p.Category = 2
           THEN 'Active '
           ELSE 'Departed'
       END AS Matrix
     , p.name AS [Name]
FROM #People p
ORDER BY p.Category

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Best Employee' AS Matrix
     , 'Alan' AS [Name]
```

Your second example from the question can be written in a simpler form, without sub-query:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN p.Category = 1
           THEN 'Very Active'
           WHEN p.Category = 2
           THEN 'Active '
           ELSE 'Departed'
       END AS Matrix
     , p.name AS [Name]
     , p.Category
FROM #People p

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Best Employee' AS Matrix
     , 'Alan' AS [Name]
     , NULL AS Category  --- or '' AS Category

ORDER BY Category;
```

In any case, the column `Category` has to be added in each `SELECT` statement of the `UNION`. I don't see how you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is that your ordering is causing the 2 tables from being mixed up, you could add a column so that the 1st select result set would be displayed first always.

```
CREATE TABLE #People(Category varchar(50), [Name]  varchar(50));

INSERT INTO #People VALUES(1, 'Steve');
INSERT INTO #People VALUES(99, 'Anna');
INSERT INTO #People VALUES(2, 'Sarah'); 

SELECT Matrix, Name, Category
FROM
(
    -- Unrelated data SELECT query
    SELECT 'Best Employee' AS Matrix
         , 'Alan' AS [Name]
         , '' AS Category
         , 1 as Ord

UNION ALL

    SELECT CASE
               WHEN p.Category = 1
               THEN 'Very Active'
               WHEN p.Category = 2
               THEN 'Active '
               ELSE 'Departed'
           END Matrix
         , p.name AS [Name]
         , p.Category Category,
         2 as Ord
    FROM #People p
) x
ORDER BY x.Ord --,Additional Order by columns
```

Comment: It's not the ordering that I'm worried about just the sheer number of `SELECT` statements really. My hope was to only having to change the statement with the `ORDER BY` and leave all others as they are.